# JavaScript csv parsing with array including the delimiter, not to be parsed

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, csv, parsing

I am encountering a problem with a csv file that contains some header, attached to an array of that form `array = [[val01,val02],[val11,val12],...]`. In all I have something like this:

```
key1, key 2, ...., key k, .... key n   // Line 1
val1, val 2, ...., array, .... val n   // Line 2
```

I am using the CSV Parser function from [CSVToArray() function](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm) from Ben Nadel, discovered here too. However, not being very much fluent with Regex, I can't manage to stop the parser to parse the array too. Any idea?

Here is the Parser delimiter details:

```
`// Delimiters.
"(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +
// Quoted fields.
"(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +
// Standard fields.
"([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"`
```

Thanks